# Use Button as Link in Eclipse RAP/RWT Web Application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rap

I have a little Web-Application with some Buttons. When I click on one button I would like to follow a link to a new EntryPoint. While I can add Markup to a Label it is not possible with a Button. I found

```
UrlLauncher launcher = RWT.getClient().getService( UrlLauncher.class );
launcher.openURL( "http://www.eclipse.org/" );
```

But that will open a new Tab/window and that is not the desired behaviour.
So: Is there a way to have the Button "behave" like a Link when pushed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to replace the RAP application with a website of your choice in the current browser tab:

```
final JavaScriptExecutor jsex = RWT.getClient().getService( JavaScriptExecutor.class );
if (jsex!=null){
  jsex.execute(
    "parent.window.location.href=\"http://www.eclipse.org\";"
  );
}
```